# Can anyone tell me what's wrong here ? I'm trying to extract columns where all elements are same, but it's not working

Tags: r

my data set is called "train". it has 705 columns and 50006 rows. I'm trying to extract the columns where every element is same. But R throws some error.

code

```
silly_var<-list()
for (i in 1:705) {
  for (j in 1:50006){
    if train[1,i]==train[j,i] {
      if j == 50006 {
        list.append(silly_var,colnames(train)[i])
      }
    }else break
  }
}
```

Error message

```
> silly_var<-list()
> for (i in 1:705) {
+   for (j in 1:50006){
+     if train[1,i]==train[j,i] {
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  for (j in 1:50006){
    if train"
>       if j == 50006 {
Error: unexpected symbol in "      if j"
>         list.append(silly_var,colnames(train)[i])
[[1]]
[1] "support_search_events"

>       }
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     }else break
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the `for` loops, you need parentheses around your `if` statement conditions.

```
if (train[1,i]==train[j,i]) {
  if (j == 50006) {
    list.append(silly_var,colnames(train)[i])
  }
}else break
```